# Any idea about array; I am doing array list project

Tags: java, arrays

I wanted the output to be like this using array list but my code is not giving me the right output.

[image: output]

My code is:

```
        package studentraanking;

          import java.util.*;

           public class Studentraanking {

             public static void main(String[] args) {


                System.out.println("Enter # of Students:");
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                int arraySize = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter # of Subjects");
                Scanner sub = new Scanner(System.in);
                int arrays = sub.nextInt();
                ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

                ArrayList<String> arraysss = new ArrayList<String>();

                 System.out.println("Enter "+arrays+" Subjects");
                for (int i = 0; i < arrays; i++) {

                    String sj = input.next();
                    array.add(sj);



                for (int x = 0; x < arraySize; x++) {

                    System.out.print((x+1)+". Name:");
                    String arval = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Grade in : " + sj );
                    int grade = input.nextInt();
                    arraysss.add(arval);
                }





                }
             }

              }
```

[image: wrong output of my code]

I wanted to finish entering all the subjects before asking the name of the student then ask his grade for every subjects that i entered please help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you nested your for loops. Do this:

```
//Input all your subjects
for (int i = 0; i < arrays; i++) {
    //input all your subjects
    String sj = input.next();
    array.add(sj);


}//this is the closing brace for the first for loop, which you had surrounding the loop below


 //input your grades
for (int x = 0; x < arraySize; x++) {

     System.out.print((x+1)+". Name:");
     String arval = input.next();
     System.out.println("Grade in : " + array.get(x) );
     int grade = input.nextInt();
     arraysss.add(arval);
}
```

Comment: but if i did that i cant call the sj that I added in array it gives me error

Comment: @cubedash That is a different problem. But you could do something like I suggested. You basically don't use `sj`, you use the array that you created in the first loop. I updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you.